# Typescript not narrowing fields of item that's part of a union of generic types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, generics, narrowing

I'm trying to come up with a pattern for a react component that renders multiple steps of some user flow. What I've got so far is:

```
interface Step<T extends string, P extends FC<any>> {
  id: T;
  component: P;
  getProps: (state: ComponentState) => P extends FC<infer R> ? R : never;
}

type UseStepsHook<T extends Step> = {
  steps: T[];
  currentStep: T;
}

function useSteps<T extends Step>(steps: T[]): UseStepsHook<T>;
// hook implementation...

const makeStep<T extends string, U extends FC<any>> = (
  id: T,
  component: U,
  getProps: Step<T, U>['getProps']
): Step<T, U> => ({
  id,
  component,
  getProps
});

const FooComponent: FC<{foo: string}> = ({foo}) => <div>{foo}</div>;
const BarComponent: FC<{bar: string}> = ({bar}) => <div>{bar}</div>;

const stepFoo = makeStep('foo', FooComponent, (state) => ({foo: state.foo}));
const stepBar = makeStep('bar', FooComponent, (state) => ({bar: state.bar}));

type StepFoo = typeof stepFoo;
type StepBar = typeof stepBar;

type Steps = StepFoo | StepBar;

const MultiStepComponent = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'});
  const { currentStep } = useSteps([ stepFoo, stepBar ]);
  const Component = currentStep.component;
  const props = currentStep.getProps(state);
  return <Component {...props} />; // <-- TS error
}
```

`currentStep` has the union type `StepFoo | StepBar` as expected, but the last line trying to render the current step gives this error:

```
Type '{ foo: string; } | { bar: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { foo: string; } & { bar: string; }'.
  Property 'bar' is missing in type '{ foo: string; }' but required in type '{ bar: string; }'.
```

I can get it to wrok if I narrow the type down by `id`, or if I cast `currentStep` as a generic `Step`:

```
const MultiStepComponent = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'});
  const { currentStep } = useSteps([ stepFoo, stepBar ]);

  if(currentStep.id === 'foo'){
    const Component = currentStep.component;
    const props = currentStep.getProps(state);
    return <Component {...props} />; // <-- NO ERROR
  }
  
  const _curr = currentStep as Step;
  const Component = _curr.component;
  const props = _curr.getProps(state);

  return <Component {...props} />; // <-- NO ERROR
}
```

But these seem like redundant steps to take, since I know the Component and props will always match because of how the generic is defined. Is there any way to get Typescript to read this situation more "intuitively"?

Even if there isn't, any example or explanation of WHY Typescript raises this error would be much appreciated